# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
<p class="test">
<?php  
    $button_value = get_field('button_name');
    echo $button_value;
    if ($button_value == 1) {
        <a href="?page_id=26" class="get_quote">get quote</a> 
    }
?>  
</p>
```

This is the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/dgsite81/public_html/dgprint/wp-content/themes/dgprint/index.php on line 122
```

Comment: syntax errors are off-topic, which this one is obvious.

Comment: I know it is common but simply not found

Comment: `<p class="test">
    <?php  
    $button_value = get_field('button_name');
    echo $button_value;
    if($button_value==1)
    {
    echo '<a href="?page_id=26" class="get_quote">get quote</a> ';
    }
    ?>  
    </p>`

Comment: they close them before I can even answer.  good luck dude.

Comment: @RightClick as they should.

Comment: I thought downvoting hid the silly ones.  I'm often 95% done an answer and then it's closed

Comment: the better way to have "answered" this, would have been *"you're injecting pure HTML into PHP"*. (Teach a person HOW to fish...) you know the rest.

Comment: well I had a sweet answer all ready with an explanation but it doesn't fit in a comment.  oh well, someone else apparently can still answer.  It's just a frustrating dynamic on here sometimes, nothing personal

Comment: A better way to do it so that you don't need to echo static html.  Close your php tag, write your html code and then open up your php tag again like so: ?><a href="?page_id=26" class="get_quote">get quote</a><?php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="?page_id=26" class="get_quote">get quote</a>';
```

Comment: given an added explanation, would benefit the OP to learn from their mistake. This answer has none. It's dropped in code. [Oh, I guess I did that already...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988756/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-php#comment50007604_30988756)

Comment: Protip: Giving a good explanation, potentially attracts more upvotes ;-)

Comment: agree but this one was enough self-explanatory ;-)